# What is the best way to append a vector of ones?

Tags: c++, vector

```
int n = get_n(); 
std::vector<int64_t> v{4};
// append n 1s to v here?
```

I usually just create a vector of ones and move:

```
std::vector<int64_t> ones(n, 1);
std::move(ones.begin(), ones.end(), std::back_inserter(v));
```

Is there a better approach than what I have done here?

Comment: In this particular case there won't be any difference between `std::move` and `std::copy`. There is nothing to move here.

Comment: @Evg Isn't `ones` moved to the back of `v` here?

Comment: What `std::move` does is essentially this: `int i = 1; v.push_back(std::move(i));`. Here `std::move` is completely redundant.

Comment: @Evg Oh I see, I thought it'll somehow append the pointer `ones.data()` to the end of `v`.

Answer (score 5):

[`std::vector::resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) has the second optional argument for a default value of newly inserted elements, so you can do

```
v.resize(v.size() + n, 1);
```

to add `n` ones.

This is likely to be more efficient than any code that uses `std::back_inserter(v)` because no capacity checks will be made at each insertion and at most one reallocation will happen.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, that doesn't depend on `std::back_inserter(v)`, uses one of the overloads of [`std::vector::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert), which accepts a count parameter:

```
v.insert(v.end(), n, 1);
```

Its complexity, in this case, should be linear in `n` (plus the possible reallocation), like `std::vector::resize`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [std::fill_n](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(v), n, 1);
```